# CryptoJS decryption fails when string with Unicode emosy chars

Tags: javascript, encryption, unicode, cryptojs

I use CryptoJS for encryption and decryption of message in my app. Here is my code.

**//encryption**

```
var msg = "Hello";
var passStr= '54472f2f7a7c41da0a001739';
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('0000000000000000');
var passSHA256 = CryptoJS.SHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(passStr));

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(messageStr, passSHA256, { iv: iv });
var messageTosend = encrypted.toString();
```

**//decryption**

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(messageTosend , passSHA256, { iv: iv });
var messageGot = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

This works fine but some time fails with error( Malformed UTF-8 data)  when message contains Unicode chars like this.

```
msg = "".
```

This gives me empty string.

Comment: In general, for decryption you *undo* all the steps you did for encryption. So why do you need this line `var messageGot = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);` when you have no matching line in the encrypt method? Either get rid of this line, or add a corresponding CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse step in the encrypt direction.

Comment: Having the same issue , using  the AES cipher  when my encrypted string has characters like '00XX00+XX'  , it is being sent as '00XX00 XX' to the server and decryption fails !